# Not able to connect adb after upgrate Android Studio to 3.4

Tags: android-studio, build, adb, android-studio-3.4

> unable to connect to adb.check the event log for a possible issue, verify that localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1 or:: 1 for ipv4 or ipv6

[image]

Tried adb kill-server, restart, invalidate restart nothing works.
Same issue reported over here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130791561

**Note:** I have not added any file or anything in studio, it's fresh installed Studio after format a full system still issue is there.

Comment: I have tried with uninstalling the studio and full format the system after that it's also not working.

Comment: you might not have added platform-tools into the path... can you run `adb.exe`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler it say's api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing

Comment: see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: @ram working with https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897920/8603832

Comment: I guess it requires windows to be updated as mentioned in one of the posts, coz in my case when it didn't work I wanted to do a restart but it had an option of "update and restart" so when done, it worked fine

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Replace your platform-tools with this one and delete the other one.
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

Comment: Your answer is not applicable for Mac or Linux users.

Comment: **Restarting PC** is gonna be needed

Comment: Android SDK -> SDK Tools ->
Remove "Android SDK Platform-Tools" and reinstall it. Restart PC should resolve this problem. Worked perfectly in Linux.

Comment: when i use only Genymotion i faced this error : unable to connect to adb.check the event log for a possible issue, verify that localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1 or:: 1 for ipv4 or ipv6 .... this soulution worked for me .

Comment: It's not a proper solution, I have solved the same issue by referring to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948774/not-able-to-connect-adb-android-studio-to-3-4-1/56948963#56948963

Comment: Downgrading platform-tool from higher version to 26 is not a perfect answer. anyway it solve the issue.

Comment: @abasnikzad For me the issue was starting Genymotion device before starting adb, I closed my Genymotion device and then first started adb after that running Genymotion device resolved this issue. Main Issue I feel here is that the port adb required to start was occupied by Genymotion so it can happen with other applications too like Skype

Answer (score 23):

I was also facing this issue in android Studio 3.4 version, but now I have fixed it , if you are using windows then follow these steps:

1. Download Platform tools from here
   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip
2. Extract downloaded zip file
3. Go To location "C:\Users\your_computer_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" and Delete "Platform tools" folder
4. Copy and Paste, downloaded platform tool folder to above location
5. Now Go to your android studio and Rebuild your project Then run.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to restart my PC after replacing the tool to make it work.

Comment: What of mac users?

Comment: @Idris Stack, its look like a bug and many Android Studio's users facing this issue in version 3.4 so trying to install lower version than 3.4, until this issue is fix by Android Studio's developer team.

Comment: @Basant, I have seen the answer from lutaaya. It has helped me.

Answer (score 11):

For **Mac** Users, follow these simple steps :

1. Just simply Navigate to **Tools > SDK Manager> Android SDK>**, then click on the Tab of **SDK Tools**, then look for `Android SDK Platform-tools` and update it.
2. Then the last step, **Invalidate cache and restart your IDE**, after that, then finally you r**estart your Mac**. (*Sometimes it's this step is unnecessary*)

**It will work out successfully.**

[image]

Comment: this worked for me on my mac. Upgrade and invalidate-restart IDE was good enough

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for Linux Users.**

**System info:** Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1 , Android Studio 3.4.1

**Issue description:** Problem with platform tools.

**Solution:** Remove the folder manually and update SDK tools through Android Studio.

**Step 1:** Go to your Android SDK installation folder. By default under your home directory. Choose platform-tools and simply delete. (/home//Android/SDK)

[image]

**Step 2:** Open Android Studio and go to SDK Tools. (File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools) By the moment you should be able to see Android SDK Platform Tools line unchecked.

[image]

**Step 3:** Put a check to install Platform Tools and press OK. Notice it'll relocate the folder to the directory where deleted.

[image]

Now that you re-installed the platform tools, restart the Android Studio and your deployment targets should show up.

[image]

If you don't install the platform tool back and ever try to build or run a project you'll get this IDE error. Just FYI :)

[image]

So that's all. Enjoy.
Happy coding

Comment: Hi Gulbala, My mobile device is not connecting to android studio through USB, I have checked with platform tools 26 and 29, but no luck, I am using windows 7PC. please help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Windows, you might have a corruption in `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`. 
Try to update it - you can get the update from [Microsoft's website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows).

You should check it - `path/to/sdk/platform-tools` and try to run adb.exe

Comment: i have installed fresh windows issue is still present old and new windows,before it working fine after update to 3.4 it cause the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you update Sdk platform tools(which contains adb.exe) to release 28.0.2 and if you are using windows 8.1 then it needs few updates from windows.

As per SDK Platform tools release notes(https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools):

> Updated Windows requirements : The platform tools now depend on the Windows Universal C Runtime, which is usually installed by default via Windows Update. If you see errors mentioning missing DLLs, you may need to manually fetch and install the runtime package."

Windows update url: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Prerequisite for Windows update url: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327

Faced the exact same issue but after updating with prerequisite url first then the other url provided now it is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I had faced exactly the same problem but it got resolved after the updates.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by selecting **-> Use libusb backend**

[image: It worked for me by selecting]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Windows:

1. Goto cmd write %temp% hit enter -> delete all data from there.
2. Restart your Computer.
3. Open Android Studio now, it will work.

Comment: Simple solution but some of need to be reminded to restart our machines.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear all cache memory (related to Android Studio)
2. Restart ADB manually from Android Studio (first option)

Open Command prompt and got android sdk>platform-tools> adb kill-server

press enter

and again  adb start-server

press enter

3. Restart ADB manually form Android Stidio (second option)

go to your (SDK store path)  sdk>platform-tools>adb

press enter

ex. D drive > sdk>platform-tools>adb

4. Restart your system

Comment: Other option is first replace your platform-tools after that follow above step.

Comment: Replace your platform-tools with other one.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the platform-tools folder from the sdk and replacing with the same from your another pc. I am also facing this problem after updating to 3.4. If you face same problem please update to Android Studio 3.5 Canary Channel.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is for ADB server problem. Simply re-run your adb.

(Go to your SDK folder then inside platform-tools folder you can see adb.exe. copy the path location and paste it in your computers system Environment variable. Set a new path there and paste the adb.exe file location there. hope it will solve )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Genymotion, there is an update that fix the problem.

[Genymotion 3.0.2 (April 18th, 2019)](https://www.genymotion.com/product-release-note/desktop/)

> **Corrections**
>
> We have fixed an
>   incompatibility with the adb tool bundled in the platform-tools 28.0.2
>   package of the Android SDK, which caused failures to start virtual
>   devices.
>
> This new version of adb changed the behavior of the “adb connect
>   :” command by making the “port” part mandatory. This
>   broke Genymotion Desktop in a few places where it did not pass the
>   port. We have adjusted the way we call “adb connect” and also updated
>   the version we ship with the product to match the one in
>   platform-tools 28.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

If non of the above answers worked for you (as same happend to me), down grade to the old version of Android Studio by following these steps:

1. Uninstall current Android Studio
2. Go to [Android Studio Archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) and download any older version
3. After installation, Open the project. You might see an error like this

> This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.4 or newer.

4. Now, open project gradle and update classpath `tools.build` version. I.e. in my case Android studio version is `3.2` and classpath `3.2.1`

Hope it might save someone time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue last night, and I tried these methods to fix:

- download older platform-tools and place it in the android sdk folder.(not work for me)
- `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`.(not work for me, adb had no response with these cmd)
- kill the process that occupies port 5037.(for me, there is no other .exe run at this port)
- reinstall platform-tools in Android Studio.(not work)
- download [ADB Kits](http://adbshell.com/downloads) and replace them in platform-tools folder.(**work!!!**)

It seems that my adb file has been modified or replaced by some programs. You can try these methods, and I hope some of them can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue only after a Genymotion update, on Mac.

What worked for me: Open Genymotion preferences, Select ADB, choose "Use custom Android SDK tools" and points to your Android SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is not with the android studio version 3.4
Problem is with the android platform tools version which is latest one 29.

So install the previous version of the android platform tools version it will solve your problem. as above @Ved mentioned.

Ved link: 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

Answer (score 0):

EndTask adb.exe from Background processes (TaskManager) and Run Application again.
It works for me