# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.3.1 ,2.3]",

Tags: android, build, azure-devops, single-sign-on, android-manifest

I tried to add the SSO to my project I referred this link [sso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android)

After adding this line in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
//Microsoft
implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.2.+'
```

am getting the following error

```
   In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.3.1
,2.3]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.7 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2
.3.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity.client:msal@0.2.+
-- Project 'app' depends onto net.minidev:json-smart@{strictly 2.3}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@{strictly 5.7}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity.client:msal@{strictly 0.2.2}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity:common@{strictly 0.0.8}

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.
```

build file (Module:app)
 //

```
FireBase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'


    // GMS:play-services
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1'
        //Constrain layout
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

        //Microsoft 
        implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.2.+'
```

So can some one suggest me how to resolve this issue
Also I tried following things

I tried the following things
1 Updated the google play services in SDK manager
2 Updated SDK build tools  in SDK manager

So can some one suggest me how to resolve this issue

Comment: what about `0.1.0` version ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Sorry..Which u telling I cant get you

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue here...Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yeah update the windows tool. Check this below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762216/not-able-to-connect-adb-after-upgrate-android-studio-to-3-4

Answer (score 6):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57479692/5199320) that suggests disabling version check of Google Play Services is outdated. Please update `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `4.3.3`+.

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 4):

Disabling Google Play Services Version is a potential solution. In your **app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
googleServices {
    disableVersionCheck = true
}
```

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'. I found this error by applying this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

at the end of `android/app/build.gradle`