# Not able to connect adb Android Studio to 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

unable to connect to adb.check the event log for a possible issue, verify that localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1 or:: 1 for ipv4 or ipv6.

Getting an error while running my sample application in android device.

ADB error on a fresh installation of android studio.

[image]

Comment: update your sdk packages.

Comment: Updating the platform-tools is not working. I am trying with platform-tool 29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to connect adb after upgrate Android Studio to 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762216/not-able-to-connect-adb-after-upgrate-android-studio-to-3-4)

Comment: @MudassirKhan Downgrading is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got answer for my own question. This is due to some Windows OS update issue. Please follow the below step to confirm.

1. Goto C:\Users\bn\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
2. Open command prompt from this location and type, **adb devices**
3. If you get below error dialog, then the problem is with your windows setup and not any issues with Android Studio.

**adb command error**

[image]

Solution:

Download the package for your Windows version from below link. In my case I have downloaded "All supported x64-based versions of Windows 8.1" package and installed the exe. Once installation is complete check the adb command. It should work.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: When i tried to install windows (7 ,64bit) update it shows error => installer encountered an error 0xc8000222.  any solution?

Comment: @AdarshVijayanP Yes I am also getting sane error .. Any solution?

Comment: @fazil  No perfect solution yet. But go back to previous [platform tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897920/9427138) may fix for now. And check out   [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131883685)  google issue tracker if you also facing AAPT2 failing error after updating android studio 3.4 or gradle. It's a bug i think. They are trying to fix.